# How can I send a multi-part message to my IMI Mobile provider from my Azure function?

Tags: .net, sms

This is what our code looks like. It returns error code 7209 'Unable to send multi-part message.' I am wondering if there is another way to make this call that will work, or whether this problem is on IMI Mobile's (our SMS provder) part.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send(IList<Message> messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
      var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(messages, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = new LowerCaseNamingPolicy()
      });

      var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
      var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
      byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

      const string url = "resources/v1/messaging";
      var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) {Content = byteContent};
      return await _client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use an instance of `FormUrlEncodedContent`, `MultipartContent`, or `MultipartFormDataContent` instead of `ByteArrayContent`. Check the IMI provider API documentation (along with the docs for those types) to determine which one is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this Zareh. I have looked at IMI Mobile documentation on this and, shockingly, there is nothing on sending multi-part messages that I have found.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It's now a matter of trial-and-error, then. Try all three and see which one the API accepts.